# $(AB=BA\wedge A^*Bx=0)\implies BA^*x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X^*$ mean the conjugate transpose of matrix $X.$

I am given two matrices $A,B$ and a vector $x$ such that $AB=BA$ and $A^*Bx=0.$

> Does $BA^*x=0$ then?

It may look out of context, but such a property would help me with proving ellipticity of some differential operator. Unfortunately I am not handy with matrix algebra.

If the answer is no, would such additional assumptions like those below help?
$$A^*B^*x=0\hspace{10pt}ABx=0\hspace{10pt}B^*A=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0& 0\\
  0 &0& 0\\
  1 &0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0& 0\\
  1 &0& 0\\
  0 &0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then

$$AB=BA=A^*B^*=B^*A^*=B^*A=A^*B=0\quad \text{and}\quad AB^*x=0$$

but

$$BA^*x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$