# $(H^2=0\wedge V^2=0\wedge VH=HV)\implies VH^*H=H^*VH$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homological-algebra

I have one unsolved problem related to the ellipticity of some linear differential operator.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833797/ab-ba-wedge-abx-0-implies-bax-0), I guess, I oversimplified the assumptions and the answer was not as I suspected.

So let $X^*$ mean the conjugate transpose of matrix $X.$

Assume that we have two matrices $H,V$ such that $(H^2=0\wedge V^2=0\wedge VH=HV).$

> **Question.** Does $VH^*H=H^*VH$ then?

I hope this holds. If not, I am close to doomed.

PS. I added homological-algebra tag cause I guess some trics associated with assumption $H^2 = 0\wedge V^2 = 0$ migth be needed.

Comment: Taking the conjugate transpose on both sides and rearranging, we can rephrase the question as whether
$$
H^*(HV^* - V^*H) = 0
$$
which looks nicer to me, somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are close to doomed after all. For example, consider
$$
H=V=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$

Comment: Yes, it works. I am little bit angry and I honestly thank you very much.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could give me some hints with non-simplified verison of this problem which I posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122908/hx-vy-wedge-vx-hz-wedge-va-x-hb-wedge-h2-0-wedge-v2-0-wedge-vh-hv-i